# Apache Ignite Design and best practices

Tags: ignite

I am new to apache ignite and my client is having an requirement to implement it.

Basically we have an application which runs in Jboss EAP7. currently the application is using around 50 reference data tables which are static in nature. The overall record would be around 50 thousand.

This is a 3 layered application i.e. DAO, service and presentation. I am looking for best practices from design perspective that will fit this kind of applications.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take your time to look around, take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). As it stands, your question is a bit too broad for this site and asking for recommendations are off topic. It would be best or you to research the topic on your own and then come back for any _specific_ problems you face.

Comment: You should provide more information if you're looking for help. What exactly are you intending to use Ignite for? How does you data model look like? Did you already try anything? Etc. Here is Ignite documentation you can refer to: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs

Comment: Thanks for the response. first of all, I wanted to use ignite in standalone mode in production env. The requirement is when my JBOSS server started successfully, it should start ignite cache and read data from database and load to cache. So when we receive request , we will read the data from cache.

Comment: So, are there any issues?